# How to disallow dependencies via @Grab in Groovy script

Tags: java, security, groovy, scripting

I want to allow users to run their Groovy scripts in my Java server app, but I also want disallow them to use `@Grab` for adding any random dependencies.

Yes, I can simply cut off all `@Grab` annotations by search & replace in source code, but it will be better to do this in more elegant way, e.g. allow approved dependencies only.

And yes, I know that the best solution of this prob is JVM's `SecurityManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various approaches, such as the [Groovy Sandbox](http://groovy-sandbox.kohsuke.org/), which may work better than what you're about to see.

```
import groovy.grape.Grape

Grape.metaClass.static.grab = {String endorsed ->
    throw new SecurityException("Oh no you didn't! Grabbing is forbidden.")
}

Grape.metaClass.static.grab = {Map dependency ->
    throw new SecurityException("Oh no you didn't! Grabbing is forbidden.")
}

Grape.metaClass.static.grab = {Map args, Map dependency ->
    throw new SecurityException("Oh no you didn't! Grabbing is forbidden.")
}

def source1 = '''
println('This is a nice safe Groovy script.')
'''

def source2 = '''
@Grab('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1')

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator

def emailValidator = EmailValidator.getInstance();

assert emailValidator.isValid('what.a.shame@us.elections.gov')
assert !emailValidator.isValid('an_invalid_emai_address')

println 'You should not see this message!'
'''

def script
def shell = new GroovyShell()

try {
    script = shell.parse(source1)
    script.run()
} catch (Exception e) { 
    assert false, "Oh, oh. That wasn't supposed to happen :("
}    

try {
    script = shell.parse(source2)
    assert false, "Oh, oh. That wasn't supposed to happen :("
} catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e) { 
    println 'Naughty script was blocked when parsed.'
}
```

The example above demonstrates how to block @Grab. It does this not by blocking the annotation, but by overriding the method call added by the annotation: groovy.grape.Grape.grab().

```
Grape.metaClass.static.grab = {String endorsed ->
    throw new SecurityException("Oh no you didn't! Grabbing is forbidden.")
}

Grape.metaClass.static.grab = {Map dependency ->
    throw new SecurityException("Oh no you didn't! Grabbing is forbidden.")
}

Grape.metaClass.static.grab = {Map args, Map dependency ->
    throw new SecurityException("Oh no you didn't! Grabbing is forbidden.")
}
```

Here's the *naughty* script dissected by the Groovy Console AST viewer:

```
@groovy.lang.Grab(module = 'commons-validator', group = 'commons-validator', version = '1.4.1')
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator as EmailValidator

public class script1440223706571 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    private static org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo $staticClassInfo 
    public static transient boolean __$stMC 

    public script1440223706571() {
    }

    public script1440223706571(groovy.lang.Binding context) {
        super(context)
    }

    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(script1440223706571, args)
    }

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        java.lang.Object emailValidator = org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator.getInstance()
        assert emailValidator.isValid('what.a.shame@us.elections.gov') : null
        assert !(emailValidator.isValid('an_invalid_emai_address')) : null
        return null
    }

    static { 
        groovy.grape.Grape.grab([:], ['group': 'commons-validator', 'module': 'commons-validator', 'version': '1.4.1'])
    }

    protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass() {
    }

}
```

Here you can see the call to Grape.grab() in the static initializer. To add fine-grained filtering of dependencies, you can introspect the dependency and endorsed parameters.

### dependency

['group': 'commons-validator', 'module': 'commons-validator', 'version': '1.4.1']

### endorsed

commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1

## Revised Implementation

This new implementation uses an Interceptor to block/allow Grape grabs.

```
import groovy.grape.GrapeIvy

def source1 = '''
println('This is a nice safe Groovy script.')
'''

def source2 = '''
@Grab('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1')

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator

def emailValidator = EmailValidator.getInstance();

assert emailValidator.isValid('what.a.shame@us.elections.gov')
assert !emailValidator.isValid('an_invalid_emai_address')

println 'You should not see this message!'
'''

def script
def shell = new GroovyShell()
def proxy = ProxyMetaClass.getInstance(GrapeIvy)

proxy.interceptor = new GrapeInterceptor({group, module, version ->
    if(group == 'commons-validator' && module == 'commons-validator') false
    else true
})

proxy.use {
    shell.parse(source1).run()

    try {
        shell.parse(source2).run()
    } catch (org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException e) {
        assert e.message.contains('unable to resolve class')
    }
}

@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
class GrapeInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private boolean invokeMethod = true
    Closure authorizer

    def afterInvoke(Object object, String methodName, Object[] arguments, Object result) {
        invokeMethod = true

        return result
    }

    def beforeInvoke(Object object, String methodName, Object[] arguments) {
        if(methodName == 'createGrabRecord') {
            def dependencies = arguments[0]
            invokeMethod = authorizer(dependencies.group, dependencies.module, dependencies.version)
        } else {
            invokeMethod = true
        }

        return null
    }

    boolean doInvoke() { invokeMethod }
}
```

The GrapeInterceptor constructor takes a Closure as its only argument. With this Closure you can easily decide whether to allow the Grab to occur or not :)

For example, if the Grab looks like this: @Grab('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1')

The Closure's arguments would be assigned as follows:

- group: commons-validator
- module: commons-validator
- version: 1.4.1

To allow the Grab, the Closure must return true. Return false to block it.

Comment: Nice, too much work that should be done by hand, but still possible to implement. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer to include a better solution. One that will allow you to selectively allow/block Grabs.

Comment: Better, thanks! The only complaint against this solution is that I have to know too much details about `GrapeIvy` implementation, i.e. `createGrabRecord` method, but definitely better and will be usable. What's the magic of `ProxyMetaClass`!

Comment: You're welcome. The ProxyMetaClass is awesome indeed. I'm not sure what you mean by having to know too many details. The (custom) GrapeInterceptor handles the details. All you need to do create create an instance of it, and then use it with the proxy. You can even create a factory class or method to return a proxy that's ready for use.